# DB2 for i equivalent of MSSQL's Show Query Execution Plan

Tags: query-performance, execution-plan, db2

I'm a DB2 newcomer and I'm hoping that DB2 for i has an equivalent to MS SQL's Show Query Execution path.

If so, what's it called, how do I access it, and what permissions do I need to use it?

Thank you!

Comment: I guess that might depend on what tool you use to access the database. For example, System i Navigator has [Visual Explain](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_74/rzajq/visexpl.htm)

Comment: Right now, @mustaccio, I'm using DBeaver. That said, I'm fine shifting tools if need be. I'll go see if I can find System i Navigator for Windows.

Comment: @mustaccio Would you do me a kind favor and leave an answer for VisualExplain so I can mark it? It looks to be just what I'm looking for.

Comment: Please feel free to answer your own question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per @mustachhio's comment, the tool I was looking for was VisualExplain in the System i Navigator.